# arc gis javascript API Capturing polygon "onclick" event data to pass as featureset

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geoprocessing

How can you figure out what polygon is clicked within a feature layer?  I have a feature layer made of county polygons.  When the layer is clicked I want to trigger a geoprocessing task on my server.  One of the inputs to the task is a polygon.  I can't figure out how to get the clicked polygon data from the onclick event.

This is my attempt at starting but can't figure out how to get the polygon from evt.

```
 gp = new Geoprocessor("http://myserver/arcgis/services/IntersectSumJoin/GPServer/Model");
        gp.setOutputSpatialReference({ wkid: 4326 });

        paCounties.on("click", getData);

        function getData(evt) {
            console.log("In GetData The Event graphic is "+evt.Graphic+"Point is ", evt.mapPoint.x)

        }
```

The output in console is this.

I can't find a good sample that captures the Polygon in which the user clicks.

> In GetData The Event graphic is undefinedPoint is -8619169.218412401

Comment: I've both answered and voted down this question.  Have you even tried to google or look at the ESRI samples? You need to put in a little more effort before asking a question like this. https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/

Comment: @CLJ I actually did research this for a couple hours.  I did come across a few examples that showed identify and query but I kept thinking there had to be a function I was missing for a feature layer.  When you click a polygon in a feature layer it outlines and gives you the data for that polygon without doing a query or identify.  I was thinking there was something like paCounties.getSelectedPolygon that I was missing but apparently not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example of what you are looking for: https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/query_deferred_list.html